# Open specific folder in Dropbox Chooser

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

Is it possible to specify which folder to open in Dropbox Chooser (or Dropbox API) ?
Right now it opens the root directory

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry! But we're tracking this as a feature request.

Comment: I see. Ok, may be you know, is there a way to tag files in Dropbox ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tag files," but it sounds like an unrelated question, so perhaps ask a new question (here or on the Dropbox API forum, where I think I saw a similar question today).

Comment: @smarx Is there any update about this feature request?